# I am trying to run a program using selenium TestNG

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

But I am getting below error. what needs to be done?

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.openqa.selenium.WebElement.getTagName()" because "element" is null

```
package com.privacyshieldtestcases;
import java.time.Duration;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import com.privacyshieldpageobjects.PrivacyshieldForm;

public class TC_PS_001 extends BaseClass
{
    @Test
    public void psForm() throws InterruptedException
    {
        driver.get(url);
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,Duration.ofSeconds(30));
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("pt1:r1:0:it9::content")));
        PrivacyshieldForm ps = new PrivacyshieldForm(driver);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(Duration.ofSeconds(30));
        
        
        ps.setOrgName(Organizationname);
        ps.setein(einnumber);
        ps.setunsNum(DbunsNumber);
        ps.setadd1(addr1);
        ps.setCityName(cityname);
        ps.setStateName(statename);
        ps.setZipName(zipnum);
        ps.setFirstName(fname);
        ps.setLastName(lname);
        ps.setemailname(emailid);
        ps.setemailname(Confirmemailid);
        ps.setPhonenum(Pnum);
        
        ps.setSelectpay();
        ps.setpaynowbutton();
        if(driver.findElement(By.id("pt1:r1:1:s1:it1::content")).isDisplayed())
        {
            Assert.assertTrue(true);
            
        }
        else
        {
            Assert.assertTrue(false);
        }
    }}
```

Comment: Please get familiar with: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Kindly provide code so that we can help you better. From the given error i can say element is not intialized properly or if you called any function which return element then probably its return null which got set in element.  now on null element if you try to do any operation then it will throw null pointer exception.

Comment: Can someone please help me.